# Need to delete a file -ggdb

Tags: debian, rm

So I kinda messed up an managed to create a file named -ggdb in my home directory on a Debian distribution. I have tried surrounding it with " to make it a string literal (like so: `rm "-ggdb"`) but i get the following error: `rm: invalid option -- 'g'`...

When I try `rm "\-ggdb"` I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove '\\-ggdb': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rm -- -ggdb

rm ./-ggdb
```

Comment: As a quick clarification for future readers: the first solution works because `--` is the convention that several commands accept for "I'm done passing flags now"; the second works because it removes the "file or flag?" ambiguity by using a file *path* instead of something that the command has to guess about.

Answer (score -1):

The following command will work:

```
rm "\-ggdb"
```

Comment: Didn't work sir. Added error message to the original problem statement.